# concurrent server tcp using fork()

Tags: networking, g++, fork

am trying to handle multiple clients using fork() in concurrent server tcp.
it handles the first client but then when i run another client from linux terminal it keep on printing the else statement. its not creating child process to handle it

server

```
while(1){
comm_sock=accept(conn_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t *)&client_addr);
if(!fork()){
close(conn_sock);
send(comm_sock, "Data received", 13, 0);
close(comm_sock);
}
else{
cout<<"Parent cannot handle it"<<endl;
close(comm_sock);
}
```

can someone plz help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested your code but I think you should finish your child process when it finishes doing its stuff:

```
while(1){
    comm_sock=accept(conn_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t *)&client_addr);
    if(!fork()){
       /*Child process*/
       close(conn_sock);
       send(comm_sock, "Data received", 13, 0);
       close(comm_sock);
       _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else{
       cout<<"Parent cannot handle it"<<endl;
      close(comm_sock);
    }
}
```

Just one advice: with this code you are going to finish with loads of defunct child processes. If your parent process does not take care of them, once one child process dies it will finish with the defunct or zombie status. The parent process should be aware of the SIGCHLD signal in order to remove from your system the dead child processes.

Take a look at the man page for wait or waitpid: man wait / man waitpid

Besides there are plenty of examples about this on Internet.

Comment: no its still just executing else statement :( still thanks for ur help

Comment: Without _exit you are going to have after the first connection a child process in infinite loop creating for each loop more child processes. That is why you are seeing multiple times the message "Parent cannot handle it". Kill your child process and everything should run smoothly.